# Ansible reboot not rebooting even though '/var/run/reboot-required' exists

Tags: linux, ansible

I have tested this playbook with updating so I know that the credentials work, as well as the elevation to sudo. I have a test server with an extant /var/run/reboot-required file. I cannot get my ansible playbook to reboot the server though. This is an Ubuntu server. Playbook currently:

```
---
- hosts: server
  vars:
    ansible_user: sudo_user
    ansible_password: "password"
    become: yes
    become_user: sudo_user
    tasks:
       - name: Check if reboot required
         stat:
           path: /var/run/reboot-required
         register: reboot_required_file

       - name: Reboot if required
         reboot:
         when: reboot_required_file.stat.exists == true
```

Ive tried variations of this playbook and I cant get the playbook to reboot the server. Playbook returns:

```
PLAY [server] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
server                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Ive also tried just doing a shell command:

```
      - name:
        shell: if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then   init 6; else   wall "reboot not required"; fi
        ignore_errors: true
```

This also doesnt work.

Cheers

Comment: You do not have any tasks in this playbook, as your YAML indentation is wrong, the `tasks` keys currently belong to the vars. Unindent it once and your should at least have some tasks running.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the alignment of the tasks in the playbook. I performed the operation successfully by running the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: nodes
  become: yes
  become_user: sudo_user    
  tasks:
    - name: Check if reboot required
      stat:
        path: /var/run/reboot-required
      register: reboot_required_file
    - name: Diplay variable
      debug:
        msg: '{{reboot_required_file.stat.exists}}'
    - name: Reboot if required
      reboot:
      when: reboot_required_file.stat.exists == true
```

For the password set you may run the playbook as following and put the password in prompt:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml – ask-become-pass
```